# Converting circular structure to JSON in React Native in form

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a new record in a form.

I'm new to react native but have a lot of experience with react.

This component handles the creation of the record:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Form, Item, Input, Icon, Button } from "native-base";

export default class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      form: {
        title: '',
        desc: '',
        markdown: ''
      },
      showHide: 'none'
    }
  }

  submitForm = () => {
    this.props.createLibrary(this.state.form)
  }

  showForm = () => {
    this.state.showHide === 'none' ?
    this.setState({showHide: 'flex'}) :
    this.setState({showHide: 'none'})
  }


  render() {

    const formStyle = {
      display: this.state.showHide,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Icon
          name='pizza'
          onPress={this.showForm}
        />

        <Form style={formStyle} >
            <Item>
              <Input 
                placeholder="Title"
                name="title"
                onChange={(text) => this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, title: text,},})}
              />
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input
                placeholder="Description"
                name="desc"
                onChange={(text) => this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, desc: text,},})}
              />
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input
                placeholder="Markdown"
                name="markdown"
                onChange={(text) => this.setState({form: {...this.state.form, markdown: text,},})}
              />
            </Item>

            <Button onPress={this.submitForm}>
              <Text>Submit</Text>
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the component that has the method that creates the form:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import Card from './Card'
import NewCard from './NewCard'

export default class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        librarys: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/libraries')
      .then(res => {
        const librarys = res.data;
        this.setState({ librarys: librarys });
        console.log(this.state.librarys)
      })
  }

  //Create card
  createLibrary = (library) => {
    console.log(library)
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/libraries', {
      body: JSON.stringify({library}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: "POST"
    })
    .then((response) => {
        this.updateLibrary(library)
      })
  }
  updateLibrary(library){
    let newLibrarys = this.state.librarys.filter((f) => f.id !== library.id)
    newLibrarys.unshift(library)
    this.setState({
      librarys: newLibrarys
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <Card style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} librarys={this.state.librarys}/>
        <NewCard 
          createLibrary={this.createLibrary}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to submit the form to create a new record, this is the response that I receive: Converting circular structure to JSON

I'm recreating this app from a React app, and when I run this code in react, I do not receive the record.

This is the way my api is setup:

```
class LibrariesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_library, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /libraries
  def index
    @user = User.all

    @libraries = Library.all.order('created_at ASC')
    render :json => @libraries

  end

  # GET /libraries/1
  def show
    render json: @library
  end

  # POST /libraries
  def create
    @library = libraries.create(library_params)
    render json: @library
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /libraries/1
  def update
    if @library.update(library_params)
      render json: @library
    else
      render json: @library.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /libraries/1
  def destroy
    @library.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_library
      @library = Library.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def library_params
      params.require(:library).permit(:title, :markdown, :desc)
    end
end
```

Comment: Seems a problem into the API, not in the frontend. Did you try perform this request in the API separated, using, for example, postman? Are this request (POST /libraries) working properly?

Comment: It's throwing an error before it even gets there. This is what the object looks like that being passed in: https://imgur.com/KfNCT8G

Comment: This image is not clear. Circular JSON error cames from backend? To achieve this, looks the tab "network" in developer tools in your browser. There is a "response" tab. If this error cames from the backend, then it should be a response. This is important to identify where the JSON is indeed handled as circular, to start to solve the problem.

Comment: This is the response

Comment: So the problem is not with the request itself, but the way that the API is handling it. Can you provide some code of the API?

Comment: Just added my controller as in edit in the original post.